# Unzipping process making the device unresponsive

Tags: java, android, unzip

while running the code below to unzip a 70 mb zip file (which contains 750 files), the device becomes unresponsive and almost crashes. Can anyone tell me whats wrong with it:

```
boolean UNZipFiles() {
    float prev = -1; // to check if the percent changed and its worth updating the UI
    int finalSize = 0;
    float current = 0;

    try {
        final int BUFFER = 2048;
        String zipFilePath = PATH + FileName;

        BufferedOutputStream dest = null;
        BufferedInputStream is = null;
        ZipEntry entry;
        ZipFile zipfile = new ZipFile(zipFilePath);

        finalSize = (int) new File(zipFilePath).length();

        Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> e = zipfile.entries();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            entry = e.nextElement();
            current += entry.getCompressedSize();

            if (entry.isDirectory())
                dirChecker(entry.getName());
            else {
                int count;
                byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];

                is = new BufferedInputStream(zipfile.getInputStream(entry));
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(PATH + entry.getName());
                dest = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, BUFFER);
                while ((count = is.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1)
                    dest.write(data, 0, count);

                if (prev != current / finalSize * 100) {
                    prev = current / finalSize * 100;

                    UpdatePercentNotificationBar((int) prev);
                }

                dest.flush();
                dest.close();
                is.close();
            }
        }


        DeleteZip(zipFilePath);

        success = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        NotificationBarFail("Error while Downloading");
        return false;
    }

    return true;

}
```

Notification management:

```
public void onCreate() {        
    super.onCreate();
    mContext = this;

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
    notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "Downloading files", System.currentTimeMillis());
    notification.flags = notification.flags | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    notification.contentView = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.background_service);
    notification.contentIntent = pendingIntent;
    notification.contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.status_icon, R.drawable.icon);
    notification.contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.status_Percentage, "0%");
    notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.status_progress, 100, progress, false);

    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(42, notification);
    FileName = Main.Main_File_Name;
}
```

New code:

```
boolean UNZipFiles() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int length;
        float prev = -1; // to check if the percent changed and its worth updating the UI
        int finalSize = 0;
        float current = 0;

        try {

            String zipFile = PATH + FileName;

            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(zipFile);
            ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin);

            finalSize = (int) new File(zipFile).length();

            ZipEntry ze = null;

            while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                current += ze.getCompressedSize();
                if (ze.isDirectory())
                    dirChecker(ze.getName());
                else {
                    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(PATH + ze.getName());
                    while ((length = zin.read(buffer)) > 0)
                        fout.write(buffer, 0, length);
                    if (prev != current / finalSize * 100) {
                        prev = current / finalSize * 100;

                        UpdatePercentNotificationBar((int) prev);
                    }
                    zin.closeEntry();
                    fout.close();
                }

            }
            zin.close();
            DeleteZip(zipFile);


            success = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            NotificationBarFail("Error while downloading");
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    }
```

Comment: Perhaps you are calling this code on the main application thread.

Comment: @CommonsWare This code is being run in an IntentService. There doesnt seem to be anything wrong/can be improved in the code above? I updated the code with the whole function, it includes updating the Notification

Comment: While further testing it, I got "System UI stopped working" !!

Comment: "This code is being run in an IntentService" -- *only* if this is being called from `onHandleIntent()` will that mean that it is being run on a background thread. "There doesnt seem to be anything wrong/can be improved in the code above?" -- I'd consider a larger buffer (e.g., 8KB).

Comment: @CommonsWare Indeed the unzipping code get called from onHandleIntent(). How should I debug such a problem? I've updated the post with the Notification initialization, Can you see any problem there?

Comment: @Omar Does this code work with a smaller zip file? Also where is PATH?

Comment: @MorrisonChang This code works on all zip files, but the problem is that the phone becomes very slow and I even get a force close of the "System UI"!. I changed the code to the new code that I added to the post, and now everything is smooth but the unzipping takes a long time. PATH is a global variable.

Comment: @Omar - I was asking about where are you unzipping to. If SDCard putting 750 files there will take a while. Also you are flooding UpdatePercentNotification with events as your variable prev is a float.

Comment: @MorrisonChang That is the reason for all this problem! I just changed the logic behind the if statement and now it works smoothly! Please write an answer so I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the part of your code where you are calling UpdatePercentNotificationBar more than 100 times as your are using a float value for prev, so every loop generates a new message.

Original:

```
float prev;
...
if (prev != current / finalSize * 100) {
  prev = current / finalSize * 100;
  UpdatePercentNotificationBar((int) prev);
}
```

Should be something like:

```
int prev;
...
if (prev != (int)(current / finalSize * 100)) {
  prev = (int)(current / finalSize * 100);
  UpdatePercentNotificationBar(prev);
}
```

As you confirmed by changing this logic you are no longer flooding the UI with messages.